# Keep getting error message "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
public class NEW {
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String Position;
    int Jnum;
    String Team;

    public static void main(String[] args)   throws Exception {

        String a =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in 0 to sort by First Name\nEnter in 1 to sort by Last Name\n" +

                "Enter in 2 to sort by position\nEnter in 4 to sort by Team names");

        int q = Integer.parseInt(a);    
        File input  = new File("Roster.txt");
        Scanner players = new Scanner(input);
        NEW []  array = new NEW [435];
        int x=0;
        while (players.hasNext()){
            array[x] = new NEW();
            array[x].Firstname  = players.next();
            array[x].Lastname  = players.next();
            array[x].Position  = players.next();
            array[x].Jnum  = players.nextInt();
            array[x].Team  = players.next();
        }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, array.toString()," ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    players.close();
    }

    public static NEW[] BubbleSort(int num, NEW []array){
       int p=0;

       if (num==0){
       String temp = null;
           for(int k =1;k<435;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<435-k;i++){
            if(array[i].Firstname.compareTo(array[i+1].Firstname)>0){
              temp = array[i].Firstname;
            array[i].Firstname=array[i+1].Firstname;
            array[i+1].Firstname= temp;
            }
            p++;
        }
    }


return array;
    }


    if (num==1){
        String temp = null;
        for(int k =1;k<435;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<435-k;i++){
            if(array[i].Lastname.compareTo(array[i+1].Lastname)>0){
              temp = array[i].Lastname;
            array[i].Lastname=array[i+1].Lastname;
            array[i+1].Lastname= temp;
            }
            p++;
    }

}
return array;
}


       if (num ==2){
           String temp = null;
           for(int k =1;k<435;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<435-k;i++){
            if(array[i].Position.compareTo(array[i+1].Position)>0){
              temp = array[i].Position;
            array[i].Position=array[i+1].Position;
            array[i+1].Position= temp;
            }
            p++;
       }


           }

       return array;
       }


       if (num ==3){
           int temp = 0;
           for(int k =1;k<435;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<435-k;i++){
            if(array[i].Jnum>(array[i+1].Jnum))
              temp = array[i].Jnum;
            array[i].Jnum=array[i+1].Jnum;
            array[i+1].Jnum= temp;
            p++;
       }


           }

       return array;
       }


       if (num ==4){
           String temp = null;
           for(int k =1;k<435;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<435-k;i++){
            if(array[i].Team.compareTo(array[i+1].Team)>0){
              temp = array[i].Team;
            array[i].Team=array[i+1].Team;
            array[i+1].Team= temp;
            }
            p++;
       }


           }

       return array;
       }

       else return array;





    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the stack trace, there will be the **name of your source file** and a **line number**.  These will tell you exactly which line of code is the source of the problem, which is ultimately that you are trying to access an element of a collection where there is none. For example:

```
List<String> l = Collections.emptyList();
String s = l.get(0); //will throw NoSuchElementException
```

Or it might also indicate that you are iterating over the **end** of an `Iterator` (note that a [`Scanner` implements `Iterator<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)):

```
Iterator<String> itr = Collections.singleton("Hey").iterator();
itr.next(); // ok!
itr.next(); //will throw NoSuchElementException
```

Every time you call `next()` on an `Iterator`, the "pointer" moves forwards. If you need to access the next element more than once, you need to save it in a local variable, and *always* use `hasNext()` to check that an element is available:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String s = itr.next();
    System.out.println("Length of \"" + s + "\" is: " + s.length()); //access twice
}
```

Unless you are using `itr.remove()`, you can **take advantage** of the java **foreach** loop, which removes the need for writing much of the *boilerplate* above, although this will not work in the case of a `Scanner` (which is an `Iterator` - foreach only works on instances of `Iterable`):

```
for (String s : someIterable) {
  //can use s as many times as you want
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, isn't it? Not an *answer*.

Comment: I decided that the advice about stack traces/line numbers was "worthy" of it being an answer

Comment: I was also doing the traditional SO thing of saving and then editing my answer. I no longer think it is deserving of a downvote!

Answer (score 0):

As oxbow_lakes mentions, more information about the exception would be good.

But this code is suspicious:

```
while (players.hasNext()){

    array[x] = new NEW();
    array[x].Firstname  = players.next();

    array[x].Lastname  = players.next();

    array[x].Position  = players.next();

    array[x].Jnum  = players.nextInt();
    array[x].Team  = players.next();
}
```

If `players` has fewer than five tokens available at the top of the loop, one of those `next`s is going to fail. All that [`hasNext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) tells you is that there is at least **one** token available. You're assuming here that at least one means you have all five, which is (apparently) not a valid assumption as you're getting the exact exception that [`next`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) is documented to throw when there's no token available.

Answer (score 0):

you have used hasNext() method which actually is an enumerator() change ur array into a list... it would be much easier.. also you used next()

change it to List newelement = new LinkedList();

then the other codes..

Answer (score 0):

sir, its not that he has more than 435 in the file.. its that its less than 435..

and thats why it returned null...

he used next()

make it into a list...

atleast it would be equal to what you have inputed.. it would not be 435 but it would be equal to the length of the file...

as stated by this link

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq to learn how it works here. This is not a forum or so :) If you earn 50 reputation, then you'll be able to post *comments* on other's posts. To earn those 50 reputation you obviously have to post *fullworthy* answers first ;)